# PS4 Gamertag ID Changing

Tags: ps4

Someone has the name on playstation that I want. They haven’t played in over 2 years and I was wondering could I get their/the name that I want. I know that on Twitch if you’re affiliated and someone doesn’t stream in a certain amount of time - you can just take their user name.

Simple Form: Is there any way to take someone’s username?

Answer (score 1):

PSN IDs don't expire, at least not yet, so no, there is no way to get someone else's PSN ID, active or inactive, <strike>unless they change it themselves</strike>.

Wondercricket pointed out in the comment that [even if they change it you still can't get it](https://blog.playstation.com/2019/04/10/online-id-change-on-psn-your-questions-answered/).

Note that Sony does [reserve the right to delete accounts after 2 years of inactivity](https://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2016/08/09/new-terms-of-service-allows-sony-to-deactivate-inactive-psn-accounts/), but this is not applied with any level of consistency (if it is applied at all).

Comment: Even if they were to change it to something else, another account still wouldn't be able to take the name. This is mentioned [here](https://blog.playstation.com/2019/04/10/online-id-change-on-psn-your-questions-answered/)